# Error referencias jQuery: find() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

Tengo un sitio desarrollado en Drupal 8 y tengo el siguiente problema.

Cada vez que modifico algún ítem de un combo, disparo una llamada Ajax para modificar elementos del DOM. Sin embargo, me aparece el siguiente error:

```
An error occurred while attempting to process [...]modo=adult&ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax: ajax.$form.ajaxSubmit is not a function
```

Y si miro el inspector, veo este error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).findOnce is not a function
    at Object.detach (<anonymous>:34:59)
    at drupal.js?v=8.9.16:42
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Drupal.detachBehaviors (drupal.js?v=8.9.16:39)
    at Drupal.AjaxCommands.insert (ajax.js:539)
    at ajax.js:442
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Drupal.Ajax.success (ajax.js:440)
    at HTMLScriptElement.bigPipeProcessPlaceholderReplacement (big_pipe.js:38)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js?v=3.5.1:2)
```

Yo diría que está intentando usar alguna librería de jQuery pero no sabe cual, porqué está cargando más de 1, **la del Theme y la del Core de Drupal**.

[image: Referencias]

He intentado desactivar la llamada de la del Theme pero entonces no me carga los elementos de la página.

Quizá diga una tontería o algo ilógico, pero ¿Existe algo para detectar si está cargada alguna librería, no volverla a cargar? o algún control similar? Dónde puede estar el problema o qué puedo hacer para corregirlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que jQuery.min es una versión mínima de jQuery que no incluye las funciones para hacer llamadas AJAX

Comment: El mensaje de error es muy claro `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).findOnce is not a function`, no existe la función `findOnce()`; en todo caso, podría tratarse de [once()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/244492/jquery-once-onload), disponible en jQuery de Drupal 8 (tal vez en otras versiones también, pero lo desconozco).

Comment: Sí, pero si hago Ctrl+F5 para refrescar la página entonces no da error... Es decir, parece como si la primera vez que entras no cargue la librería bien; pero, cuando refrescas, se pone todo a sitio y funciona. Es un comportamiento muy extraño y que de cara el cliente se debería evitar a toda costa...